# How do i convert vanilla Js code into vue js code

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
//Logged out Events
document.getElementById("login-help").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".forgotten").style.display = "flex";
    document.querySelector(".login").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".signup").style.display = "none";
})

document.getElementById("forgotten-back").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".forgotten").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".login").style.display = "flex";
    document.querySelector(".signup").style.display = "none";
})

document.getElementById("signup-btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".forgotten").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".login").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".signup").style.display = "flex";
})

document.getElementById("signup-back").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".forgotten").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".login").style.display = "flex";
    document.querySelector(".signup").style.display = "none";
})
```

This is my vanilla Js code, I am trying to convert this into vue js code, however when I input this code I get an error. How can I convert my vanilla js code to vue js?

```js
<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  methods: {
    //Logged out Events
document.getElementById("login-help").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".forgotten").style.display = "flex";
    document.querySelector(".login").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".signup").style.display = "none";
})

document.getElementById("forgotten-back").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".forgotten").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".login").style.display = "flex";
    document.querySelector(".signup").style.display = "none";
})

document.getElementById("signup-btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".forgotten").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".login").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".signup").style.display = "flex";
})

document.getElementById("signup-back").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".forgotten").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".login").style.display = "flex";
    document.querySelector(".signup").style.display = "none";
})
  },
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: It's not possible to "automagically" convert Vanilla JS into Vue. This requires a rewrite of your current application. Please read up on how Vue works.

Answer (score 1):

You add click events in template section of your vue file, not in script(js) section. It usually looks like this:

```
 <button @click="yourFunction">Click me</button>
```

and then in your methods you have:

```
 methods: {
   yourFunction() {
     this.addClass = true;
   },
  }
```

and there is many ways to add styles, one of them is to bind class:

```
 <button :class="{'hidden': addClass}"
```

and you have someBool variable in data:

```
  data() {
    return {
     addClass: false,
    };
  }
```

You can read more at official docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html and https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind classes depending on action that you want to happen:
[Vue binding classes and styles](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)
Classes that you bind need to be defined by [data()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) and then [add events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) to html elements to toggle those classes or manipulate in any way